# Is an exception from a .NET method a terminating or not-terminating error?

Tags: powershell, exception, error-handling

In this [great article](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/08/03/effective-powershell-item-16-dealing-with-errors/) Keith explains the difference between terminating and non-terminating errors in Powershell. According to Keith exceptions thrown from calls to a member of a .NET object or type are non-terminating errors.

Indeed if we define this .NET class for testing:

```
$a = Add-Type 'public class bla { public static void bl() { throw new System.ApplicationException("test"); }}' -PassThru
```

And then this function:

```
function tst { 1 | write-host; $a::bl(); 2 | Write-host }
```

we will see that when tst function is called the exception appears to be non-terminating: the second `Write-Host` works.

But consider this:

```
function tst2 { try { tst } catch { "Catch!" } }
```

If we open [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793.aspx), we can read that the catch responds to or handles terminating errors in scripts. Throughout the text of the articles the errors the article is dealing with qualified as "terminating" in numerous places.

So when we run the line above the second Write-Host does NOT run but the catch block does. It seems that our non-terminating error suddenly becomes terminating.

How come?

Another observation, is that with good old trap it's still non-terminating error:

```
function tst3 { tst trap { "Trap!" } }
```

Now, from practical perspective, what I want to achieve is the following. In a block of code I want to terminate on exceptions thrown from the .NET code. I want to leave terminating errors from cmdlets terminating and non-terminating errors from cmdlets non-terminating.

How do I achieve this?

Example:

```
Do-Something
Call::Something()
Do-SomethingElse
Call::SomethingElse()
Do-YetMoreSomething
Call::YetMoreSomething()
```

I want to terminate on all the exceptions from .NET calls above. I also want to terminate on terminating errors from the cmdlets. I do not want to terminate on non-terminating errors from the cmdlets.

Comment: Isn't that definable by the $ErrorActionPreference ? Not so much as the actual terminating behavior of the code but on how the script handles it...?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yeah, this came up on the PowerShell MVP email list earlier this year.  PowerShell changes its error handling behavior for .NET exceptions depending on whether or not there is an outer try/catch.  This is just speculation but I'm guessing that this was for simple scripting scenarios.  That is, if the scripter (admin) messes up calling a .NET method and that generates an exception, the PowerShell team didn't want that to cease execution of the entire script.  Once V2 came along and introduced proper try/catch I'm guessing they had to revisit that decision and came up with the current compromise.

That said, working around this is a pain as you've discovered. You could set $ErrorActionPreference to `Stop` at the script level and then for every cmdlet that can generate non-terminating errors use the `-ErrorAction Continue` parameter.  Or you could put all of your .NET invocations within an advanced function(s) and then call that function(s) with the parameter `-ErrorAction Stop`.  I wish there was a better answer but after reviewing that MVP thread, I didn't see any better solutions.

Comment: I think there's a better solution, check out my answer. It might be of some interest.

Comment: @Alek Your solution is more or less what the OP demonstrated with the tst2 function and what I explain with this sentence ` PowerShell changes its error handling behavior for .NET exceptions depending on whether or not there is an outer try/catch`.  Given many potential functions in a module wrapping all script in a try/finally is a PITA.  The real trick here is to find a global way to change the behavior.  If you find "that" trick, let me know.  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The `Try` block turns the .NET exception into a terminating error, so you can enclose your .NET call in such a block:

```
Try { Class::RunSomeCode() } Catch { Throw }
```

So in your example your `tst` function becomes

```
function tst { 1 | write-host; Try { $a::bl() } Catch { Throw } 2 | Write-host }
```

And your .NET exception will now be terminating.

Answer (score 4):

To complement [Keith Hill's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17849307/45375):

PowerShell's error handling is complex, and matters are made worse by the fact that **the documentation conflates *two types* of terminating errors**:

- ***Statement*-terminating errors:**

  - By default, they abort the current *statement* only and *continue* execution (with the next statement).
- ***Script*-terminating errors:**

  - By default, they are *fatal*: they abort the *entire script* (more accurately, the entire call stack); the only way to generate them *directly* in PowerShell is with the `Throw` statement.

As an aside: The **third type of error are *non-terminating* errors**, whose primary purpose is to allow pipeline-processing cmdlets to report errors with respect to *specific input objects*, where such errors do not categorically prevent potentially successful processing of *further* input objects.

---

**Unhandled .NET exceptions are *statement*-terminating errors, just like statement-terminating errors reported by *cmdlets***.

As such, you cannot fundamentally handle them differently using `try` / `catch` (which acts on both statement-terminating and script-terminating errors, but non non-terminating ones):

While you can test the `[ErrorRecord]` instance available as `$_` in the `catch` block for its `.Exception` property being of type `[System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationExeption]`
(`$_.Exception -is [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationExeption]`),
it is *too late* to resume the default behavior for cmdlet-originated statement-terminating errors, because the `try` block has already been exited.

---

**Treating all statement-terminating errors as fatal**:

> I want to terminate on all the exceptions from .NET calls above. I also want to terminate on terminating errors from the cmdlets. I do not want to terminate on non-terminating errors from the cmdlets.

Use the following in your script:

```
# Escalate any statement-terminating error to a script-terminating one,
# but leave non-terminating ones alone.
# (Already script-terminating errors still terminate the script.)
trap { break }
```

`trap`, like `try` / `catch`, acts on statement-terminating and script-terminating errors (but not non-terminating ones).

Use of `break` is crucial in order to *terminate* the script; by default, or when you use `continue`, execution *continues* with the next statement after the error-causing one, which even applies to *script*-terminating errors; `continue` additionally suppresses *output* of the error record (though it is still collected in the automatic `$Error` collection).

---

**Treating *all* errors as fatal**:

Note: Failures signaled by *external programs* via their exit code, reflected in automatic variable `$LASTEXITCODE`, are *never* considered errors by PowerShell (however, an [opt-in mechanism to change that is being discussed](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3415); also, there are edge cases when an external program's stderr output indirectly triggers PowerShell errors - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4002)).

Setting:

```
 # !! Covers many, but NOT ALL scenarios - see below.
 $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
```

is ***almost* sufficient to make *all* error types fatal-by-default (script-terminating)**, but, sadly, not in all situations.

Note: Documented behavior claims that the `$ErrorActionPreference` *preference variable* only acts on *non-terminating* errors, but in reality it acts on *statement*-terminating ones *as well*; by contrast, the `-ErrorAction` *common parameter* indeed only acts on *non-terminating* errors.
As such, you do not strictly need to *combine* the preference variable with `trap { break }`.

***Hypothetically*, the above therefore makes *all* PowerShell errors fatal by default while allowing you to  *selectively override* the behavior:**

- for *non-terminating* errors: on a per-command basis with common parameter `-ErrorAction Continue/SilentlyContinue/Ignore` (again, note that this does *not* act on statement/script-terminating errors)
- for *statement/script-terminating* errors: with a command-enclosing `try` / `catch`

***In practice*, however, the approach fails for commands that happen to be implemented as *advanced functions* in a *script module***, which includes generated script modules that wrap remote cmdlets calls for *implicit remoting*:

Because of how variable scopes work in script modules, functions located in (different) script modules do NOT see the caller's preference variables (compiled cmdlets do not have this problem): see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568).

In other words:

- Functions from a different module will effectively *ignore* the caller's `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` value.
- You may not even see it coming, given that it's not obvious which commands are implemented as binary cmdlets and which as functions.
- Even if you do know which commands require a workaround, that workaround is cumbersome - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50299145/45375) of mine.

---

This [GitHub docs issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/1583) tries to give a **comprehensive overview of PowerShell's error handling and its pitfalls**.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, it seems that exceptions thrown *outside* `try`/`catch` blocks behave in a peculiar manner, which is neither a terminating nor a non-terminating error.

Compare the output of the following:

```
# Functions which create simple non-terminating errors.
function E1 { [CmdletBinding()] param() Write-Error "Error"; "E1" }
function E2 { [CmdletBinding()] param() Write-Error "Error" -ErrorAction:Stop; "E2" }

# Functions which throw .NET exceptions, inside and outside try/catch blocks.
function F1 { [CmdletBinding()] param() [DateTime]""; "F1" }
function F2 { [CmdletBinding()] param() try { [DateTime]"" } catch { throw } "F2" }

# Test functions.
function TestE1 { [CmdletBinding()] param() E1; "TestE1" }
function TestF1 { [CmdletBinding()] param() F1; "TestF1" }
function TestE2 { [CmdletBinding()] param() E2; "TestE2" }
function TestF2 { [CmdletBinding()] param() F2; "TestF2" }
function StopE1 { [CmdletBinding()] param() E1 -ErrorAction:Stop; "StopE1" }
function StopF1 { [CmdletBinding()] param() F1 -ErrorAction:Stop; "StopF1" }
function StopE2 { [CmdletBinding()] param() E2 -ErrorAction:Stop; "StopE2" }
function StopF2 { [CmdletBinding()] param() F2 -ErrorAction:Stop; "StopF2" }

# All the following call pairs display similar behavior.
TestE1        # Returns "E1", "TestE1".
TestF1        # Returns "F1", "TestF1".

TestE2        # Halts and returns nothing.
TestF2        # Halts and returns nothing.

StopE2        # Halts and returns nothing.
StopF2        # Halts and returns nothing.

# The following display different behavior.
StopE1        # Halts and returns nothing.
StopF1        # F1 halts but StopF1 doesn't; the call returns "StopF1".
```

This shows that .NET exceptions thrown outside `try`/`catch` blocks are *not* non-terminating errors, or at least not the same kind of errors generated by `Write-Error`.

To achieve consistent results, the only manner so far is to `catch` the exception and either re`throw` it (creating a terminating error) or `Write-Error` it (creating a non-terminating error). For example:

```
function F1 { [CmdletBinding()] param() try { [DateTime]"" } catch { Write-Error -ErrorRecord:$_ } "F1" }

# Now everything's fine.
TestE1        # Returns "E1", "TestE1".
TestF1        # Returns "F1", "TestF1".

StopE1        # Halts and returns nothing.
StopF1        # Halts and returns nothing.
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing, but I'm not sure I understand how this addresses my scenario. Could you please expand a little bit?

Comment: Never mind this. I thought your question was on how to manage .NET exceptions in specific code locations, not on the entire script. The answer shows how to make .NET exceptions act like terminating errors selectively. I will keep this answer here hoping it helps someone else.