# Exchange Online - Get-UserPhoto - how to catch non terminating error?

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I'm trying to export a list of all users with no photo from our Exchange Online account using powershell. I cannot get it to work and have tried various methods.

Get-UserPhoto returns this exception when there is no profile present.

```
Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Storage.UserPhotoNotFoundException: There is no photo stored here.
```

First of all I tried use **Errorvariable** against the command but received:

```
A variable that cannot be referenced in restricted language mode or a Data section is being referenced. Variables that can be referenced include the following: $PSCulture, $PSUICulture, $true, $false, and  $null.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableReferenceNotSupportedInDataSection
+ PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Next I tried  **try, catch** but the non-terminating error never calls the **catch** despite various methods followed online about setting **$ErrorActionPreference** first of all.

Any ideas ? Here is the script:

```
 $UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session 

$timestamp = $timestamp = get-date -Format "dd/M/yy-hh-mm"
$outfile = "c:\temp\" + $timestamp + "UserswithoutPhotos.txt"




$resultslist=@()
$userlist = get-user -ResultSize unlimited -RecipientTypeDetails usermailbox | where {$_.accountdisabled -ne $True}


Foreach($user in $userlist)
{
    try
    {

        $user | get-userphoto -erroraction stop 
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "ERROR: $_"
        $email= $user.userprincipalname
        $name = $user.DisplayName
        $office = $user.office
        write-host "User photo not found...adding to list : $name , $email, $office" 
        $resultslist += $user

    }
}
$resultslist | add-content $outfile 
$resultslist
```

Comment: In your `try` block, try adding `$local:ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`

Comment: [According to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-userphoto?view=exchange-ps) the cmdlet should support [common parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-5.1).  I believe even non-terminating errors get added to the `$Error` variable, though, so you should be able to do: `$Error.Clear(); command here; if ($Error) { }`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: A _local_ `$ErrorActionPreference` preference variable instance is unlikely to help, if common parameter `-ErrorAction Stop` doesn't work (also, the `local:` prefix wouldn't make a difference). Yes, non-terminating errors are reflected in `$Error` too, as, in fact, are _all_ errors - except if common parameter `-ErrorAction Ignore` is passed to a cmdlet invocation (note, however,  that `'Ignore'` cannot be set as the value of `$ErrorActionPreference` preference _variable_).

Comment: @mklement0 I try to avoid touching global preference variables when I can help it (in reference to using `$local:` scope).  I use that trick when calling methods usually so they throw errors in their try block, but don't impact the rest of the script.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: Re global scope: that's sensible - that's why in my answer I _restore_ the previous value in a `finally` block - however, setting it at least _temporarily_ is needed (so I'm speculating) to get around script-module variable-scoping issues in this case. Do note that `try` doesn't create a separate scope - a `$local:ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` inside a `try` block still stays in effect for the rest of the enclosing function / script.

Comment: @mklement0 I had thought `try` creates its own block scope (due to using a scriptblock syntax).  Good to know, thanks!

Comment: for anyone else attempting this , it turns out that Get-Mailbox has a HasPicture attribute - much faster to query this than check for exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell's error handling is notoriously tricky, especially so with cmdlets that use implicit remoting via a locally generated proxy script module.

The following idiom provides a workaround based on temporarily setting `$ErrorActionPreference` to `Stop` *globally* (of course, you may move the code for restoring the previous value outside the `foreach` loop), which ensures that even functions *from different modules* see it:

```bash
try {

  # Temporarily set $ErrorActionPreference to 'Stop' *globally*
  $prevErrorActionPreference = $global:ErrorActionPreference
  $global:ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

  $user | get-userphoto

} catch {

    Write-Host "ERROR: $_"
    $email= $user.userprincipalname
    $name = $user.DisplayName
    $office = $user.office
    write-host "User photo not found...adding to list : $name, $email, $office" 
    $resultslist += $user

} finally {  

  # Restore the previous global $ErrorActionPreference value
  $global:ErrorActionPreference = $prevErrorActionPreference

}
```

As for why this is necessary:

- *Functions* defined in modules do *not* see the caller's preference variables - unlike *cmdlets*, which do.
- The only outside scope that functions in modules see is the *global* scope.

For more information on this fundamental problem, see [GitHub issue #4568](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4568).

Answer (score 1):

You can throw your own error like so:

```
try {
    $error.Clear()
    $user | Get-UserPhoto 
    if ($error[0].CategoryInfo.Reason -eq "UserPhotoNotFoundException") {throw "UserPhotoNotFoundException" }
} catch {
    #code
}
```

Comment: That should work. However, so as not to wipe out the session's `$Error` collection, perhaps it's better to compare the entry _count_ after with the one before to determine if an error occurred.
Also, you can just rethrow the (wrapped) exception (with all metadata) with `Throw $Error[0]`.

Comment: I couldn't get this one to work , it wasn't catching . Thanks for your efforts in helping me though