# Terminating error in PowerShell not stopping function execution

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I had the following snippet in a function I'm writing to check whether a directory is writable by the current user or not:

```bsh
  # Write temp file to see if we can
  $checkPermArgs = @{
    Path = $tempFilePath
    ErrorAction = 'SilentlyContinue'
    ErrorVariable = 'wError'
  }
  Write-Verbose "Writing file ${tempFilePath}"
  "$($MyInvocation.MyCommand) check $([DateTime]::Now)" | Out-File @checkPermArgs
  
  # Check for any errors
  if( $wError ) {
    return $false
  } else {
    $true
  }
```

My understanding is that `IOException` should be a terminating error, but for some reason I'm getting continued execution of my function. If I try to write to `$tempFilePath`, and get an `IOException`, instead of terminating my function it continues and evaluates the `if( $wError )` statement, returning and displaying `$false` in the console, resulting in the following output:

```yaml
Out-File: 
Line |
  34 |  … cation.MyCommand) check $([DateTime]::Now)" | Out-File @checkPermArgs
     |                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Access to the path '/path/to/tempFile.txt' is denied.
False
```

Since the goal is to still process the error without displaying it to the end user, I realized I goofed and wrapped `Out-File` in a `try/catch` block instead, but I'm curious why a terminating error here isn't actually terminating execution of the function.

Comment: What is your `$erroractionpreference` set to?

Comment: Check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847276/is-an-exception-from-a-net-method-a-terminating-or-not-terminating-error

Comment: @DougMaurer Continue, but `$ErrorActionPrefernce` [shouldn't have an effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7#erroractionpreference) on terminating errors: `$ErrorActionPreference and the ErrorAction parameter don't affect how PowerShell responds to terminating errors that stop cmdlet processing.`

Comment: That thread answers perfectly what was going on, especially mklement0's answer. I've voted to close this as a duplicate.